# How to conceal the functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-framework

Hi,

I have my main file in which I include my javascript file.

In my javascript file I have this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  //some functions here

});
```

I want all the functions just available to this page and I know you can kinda conceal them to outside world of javascript by doing something like

```
(function(){
$document.ready(function(){
//my functions
)};
}).init();
```

but I am not 100% sure how would it be called or whether its even the right way.

Anyone shedding light on this would be a great help!

Comment: You can't really conceal Javascript. The visitor's browser needs to access it and if the browser can access it, so can the visitor. You can put the Javascript in an external file, but that is just a matter of organization - not security. You can compress the code in various ways to make it more of a task to steal, but it can all be undone as far as I know.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "conceal"? What exactly is your goal?

Comment: Are you talking about Access Modifiers?  Like `private`, `public`, `protected`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In javascript everything declared inside a function is only available inside that function (except for when you declare a variable without the keyword var).

So everything inside the function that you pass to $().ready() is only available inside that function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //all code here is scoped inside this function, so it can't be accessed
    // outside of this function

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the first comment says you can't hide them from the user, if they really want to see it, they will see it. 
You can clean them up in a way if you really wanted to, something like

```
var mySpace = {};
mySpace.init = function() {
    // your init functions here
};
```

in doc ready you just call

```
mySpace.init();
```

I am not sure if this is what you wanted but it is the way I understood the question

Answer (score 0):

```
(function(){
    var secret1 = function(msg) {console.log("Secret Message:" + msg);}
    $document.ready(function(){
        secret1("this can only be called from within");
    )};
})();
secret1("this will cause a script error");
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the thing you are looking for is a 'javascript obfuscator'.  [Here](http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/default.aspx) is an example one.  It makes the code much harder to read and copy.  But as others have said, you can't actually fully hide javascript.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that JavaScript is intrinsically a *client-side* scripting language unless using a server-side javascript application such as [node.js](http://nodejs.org/).

As long as JavaScript is being used in this way, the entirety of your code will be downloaded much like downloading a .txt file from a website. The only real difference is that the ".js" extension and its inclusion in html `<script>` tags or in an AJAX call will force the user's browser to render it as JavaScript.

If you want to make the script a little harder for the user to find, however, this is doable. I recommend having your website retrieve the script via AJAX and appending it to the DOM. You can do this with [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) or by using [Kickstrap](http://getkickstrap.com/apps) and making your script into an "app." The script won't appear as a link in the DOM and the user would really have to search for it. You can make it even more difficult (without compromising the integrity of your site) by [minifying](http://jscompress.com/) the script. This will make it run faster while inadvertently making it less human-readable on the front end.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript there is only function scope (the exception argument in try-catch being an exception). ES5 will let you use `let` (no pun intended) to achieve block scope but it wont be usefull untill majority of UAs implement it.

So your functions are concealed from the outside world, if with outside you mean outside the dom ready event.

```
$( document ).ready( function () {
    var myFunc = function () {};
} );

myFunc();// <- ReferenceError: myFunc is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't really hide the functions, as it's in the source code of a file downloaded by the client, but you can make it so they can't access your functions from javascript.

```
(function() {

    var doStuff = function() {
        // Not Accessible
        console.log('You can\'t reach me!');
    }

    return {
        'init': function() {
            // Accessible
            doStuff();
        }
    }


})().init();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about Access Modifiers like `public`, `private` etc.  Then check out [this article](http://zaman91.wordpress.com/tag/javascript-access-modifier/) on how Javascript handles this.  Here are the key components:

```
//constructor function (class)
function Maths(x, y) {
//public properties
    this.x =x;
    this.y = y;

    //public methods
    this.add = function () { _sum = x + y; return _sum; }
    this.mod = function () { _mod = x % y; return _mod; }

    //public method calls private method
    this.show = function () {
    this.add();
    this.mod();
    showResult();
}

//private variables
var _sum=0;
var _mod=0;

//private methods
function showResult() {
    alert( "sum: " + _sum + ", mod: " + _mod );
}

}
//end function

//create instance
var plus = new Maths(3, 4);
plus.show();

//static method multiply, you can use it without instance of Maths
Maths.multiply = function (x,y) {  return x * y; }

//call static method by constructor function (class) without instance of Maths
var result = Maths.multiply(5,7);
alert(result);
//output: 35
```